# Microsoft Access - Why must I be force to use form wizard

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Every time I try to create my own `form`, without using a form wizard base off a `table/query`, it doesn't seem to work with the `subform` even thought the forms are connected correctly via `master/child` links. I tried comparing my dropdownlist/form properties from a wizard version to a custom made. I don't see any difference, why would one work while the other doesn't? am I not seeing something in the background?

Is the form / dropdownlist record source not inter connected in my custom form?

EDIT:

My combo box is now updating the first subform correctly, but it is based off a wizard form. My problem now is getting the subform1 to update subform2. I know I should be creating a new thread. But do you mind taking a quick look. The second subform should be retreiving the ID from subform1 and link it to workOrderID in subform2.

The relationship

Do not be fooled by my workOrder, it is design for only 1 LotNo. However it was originally design for multiple but was change so the user can only enter 1 lot number for 1 work order.

[image]

The main form + 2 subform

Subform1 is the first to the top

Subform2 is the bottom one
[image]

The links between subform2 and subform1. Subform1 is the first one to the top in the previous picture.
[image]

Comment: I never use the wizard, and I have no trouble creating and linking subforms.  I'm not sure what you're doing, maybe the tables aren't joined properly?

Comment: When I create my own custom form, my dropdownlist doesn't seem to update the subform. It's almost like the dropdownlist isn't connected to the actual form ID, could this be the problem?

Comment: It seems as though you must be doing some incorrectly then. Check your relationships, your source object, child/master links, etc.

Comment: @OverMind I compared everything between them, and I didn't notice anything different.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this has anything to do with it, but check your relationship diagram. Is there a relationship between the 2 tables on the field you linked?

Comment: @OverMind Yes there is, and to confirm. I went to create the exact copy on a PHP Framework, where I am more comfortable working in and it worked perfectly. I honestly don't understand how Access could be so bad. Nothing I try, seems to work even thought I am abiding to the ACCESS RULES.

Comment: Provide pictures showing your links to your tables, your forms, and your form links.

Comment: Before I provide everything you ask for. Could it be, I don't know how to set up a dropdownlist (combo box) correctly? I can use the record selector and see everything change in the subform, yet my dropdownlist does nothing.

yet the row source in between the custom / wizard is the same.

Comment: I don't know? I'm not sure how you set it up or what your database looks like. I can only go on the abstract ideas you are giving. What is the dropdown list supposed to do? All I see is a question regarding Child/Master links.

Comment: @OverMind I updated the information you wanted with extra

Comment: So when you use the Wizard, the Master field is `[shipListReleaseSubform1].Form![ID]`?

Comment: http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/forms/Subform/Master-Link-Fields.asp

Comment: Are you positive your dropdown has an OnChange event that refreshes the subform?

Comment: @JohnnyBones No, it doesn't have a On change event, since I never needed one in the pass nor does the wizard create one. I do not believe in my case, it is needed.